# Alternative for sharing data deep through component hierarchy in Angular besides Input and Services

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm writing an app in Angular 14.2 where I have a set of components in a hierarchy 4-layers deep. The hierarchy is shown in the image below.

The top of the hierarchy (Card Component) has all of the data needed by all of the hierarchy. I am currently passing the data through the hierarchy using attributes and `Input`. But something always rubs me the wrong way about that pattern.

I'm thinking about moving this to a service pattern, where I inject a service into each component so they have access to the data that way. This will feel better to me, but there will be multiple card components loaded at the same time, so I have to still pass some unique identifier through the hierarchy so that I can find the correct data for this instance in the service.

My question is, does someone have an alternate way to do this? It would be great if Angular assigned a unique id to each component instance that component children could access automatically, for example, so I don't have to pass a unique key down, but I don't think this is something Angular does. Another downside here is I'll have data in the service I need to destroy when it's no longer needed.

[image]

Comment: Hello, interesting question, did you figure it out? I was thinking that maybe you could pass the child component instance itself as an argument to your service, rather than an unique identifier, and have your service be smart as to traverse the DOM in order to find who is the correct grandparent automatically...